# Serialize two arraylists at the same time

Tags: android, arraylist, xmlserializer

I have two arraylists of type String and integer named temparrlist and sizelist, respectively.
Now I need to serialize these to an XML file.
I have successfully written temparrlist, but how can I write sizelist at the same time (one element of temparrlist above one element of sizelist)?
Thank you.

my present code is as follows

```
                            for ( String msg:temparrlist  ){

                                serializer.startTag("", "files");
                                serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
                                serializer.startTag("", "filename");
                                serializer.text(msg.toString());
                                serializer.endTag("", "filename");

                                Log.d(TAG, msg.toString()+ ".....WRITEN");
                                serializer.endTag("", "files");
                            }
```

Comment: you said sizelist is integer, then what is "one element of sizelist"?

Comment: sizelist is an array of integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
 for ( String msg:temparrlist  ){
```

use

```
 for (int k=0; k<temparrlist.size(); k++) {
   String msg=temparrlist.get(k);
   Integer num=sizelist.get(k);
   ...
   serializer.text(msg.toString());
   serializer.text(num.toString());
   ...
}
```

assuming both lists are of the same size.